# VBA Macro no longer works in office 365

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, ms-office

I have a word macro working fine in Office2013.
The macro reduces the height of the last page in a document to remove trailing blank space. Later I combine serveral of these documents (converted to XPS) to one doc - without blank areas due to empty spaces on the last pages.

```
Sub SetCurPageHeight(nHeight, nPage)
  nHeight = PointsToCentimeters(nHeight)
  nHeight = nHeight + 0.5
  Dim strHeight As String
  strHeight = CStr(nHeight)
  strHeight = Replace(strHeight, ",", ".")
  WordBasic.PageSetupPaper PaperSize:=9, TopMargin:="0", _
    PageHeight:=strHeight, Orientation:=1, FirstPage:=0, _
    OtherPages:=0, _
    ApplyPropsTo:=1, FacingPages:=0, _
    SectionStart:=nPage, _
    SectionType:=1
End Sub
```

With Office365 the macro no longer works as expected. When I use it ALL pages are set to the given height - not only the last one.
I can't even find any documentation for "PageSetupPaper". And also no replacement for this functionality.
I thinmk there was a "page setup dialog" which had a "only this page" option - from that I recoreded the macro and adapted it for my needs.

Is there any documentation for PageSetupPaper - or has anyone a hint how to solve the problem with other code Office365 VBA.

Comment: Your dependency on the WordBasic command is the place to start re-writing. WordBasic was deprecated 25 years ago with the release of Office 97. Normally, you must insert a section break before any page that has different dimensions than the rest of the document, but that's not included in your code. Is that a step you've taken manually, or did the WordBasic command somehow do that for you?

Comment: «The macro reduces the height of the last page in a document to remove trailing blank space» So why not simply delete the trailing blank spaces? And, if the last item in a document is a table, minimise the key paragraph-format attributes of and hide the following paragraph break. A whole lot less work, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write the macro in a pure VBA without using `WordBasic` in the code. Read more about that in the [Converting WordBasic Macros to Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/converting-wordbasic-macros-to-visual-basic) article.

Also you may consider using the macro recorder to find the required properties and methods to get the job while you are doing the steps manually and recording them.

Comment: Even re-written, the OP's fundamental problem is that it is not possible to change the page size for only one page in a Section. Never has been possible, either.

Comment: Macro recorder can clarify such things. If it is not possible manually, the poster will not find a way to generate such code.

Comment: «Macro recorder can clarify such things» Hardly. The macro recorder is about as smart as a box of rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest approach if using Word's standard justification method is to use something like:

```
Sub Document_Minimise()
ActiveDocument.Compatibility(wdWPJustification) = True
End Sub
```

This applies WordPerfect justification to justified paragraphs in the document, compressing the text more than Word's own justification method. That alone may be sufficient to reduce the page count.

Comment: It is not about shortest page. The need is that the last page is reduced to a hight which fits the text.